# Dual boot giving boot priority to Ubuntu 14.04 (UEFI based)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I will install ubuntu in a computer with pre-installed Windwos 8, this summarize all procedures ([Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)), but something very important to me is the boot time, I want boot straight to Ubuntu (but I'll keep windows) and it would be better if the boot is fast as it is in Windows(appx 12s). But it arise some questions for me. First: I intend to use Windows few times a week then I want some way to boot straight to Ubuntu, is it easily made? Second : When I decide to run Windows, I will have to access BIOS again to change boot priorities (I suppose at least, since I don't wanna the menu asking me every time what OS I want) how it is done from Ubuntu ? (assuming F2, F10, ESC still doesn't work.) 
As I said, I still don't have Ubuntu on this machine, then I can follow any procedure (or change) in installation.

Comment: The grub boot loader will give you at boot time the option to choose which operating system you want to boot. You don't need to access the bios for this. You can also set which OS should be the default option.

Comment: If I set I default OS (which I intend to do), I will need to access bios to load Windows ?

Comment: As long as you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode not BIOS/CSM mode. But in Windows you really have to turn off the always on hibernation or fast boot. Then it will not be so fast. But that will be the only way to boot from grub, and prevent all sorts of issues.

Comment: Oldfred's comment deserves reiteration. Microsoft has employed various tricks to reduce the Windows 8 boot time. One of these is turning "shutdown" operations into suspend-to-disk operations. The problem is that filesystems are left in unsafe states, so any filesystems shared between OSes will almost certainly become damaged when dual-booting like this. (This includes the critically important EFI System Partition, or ESP, where boot loaders are stored.) Disabling the fast boot options will increase boot times. This is a *NECESSARY* price of dual-booting with Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[...] in Windows you really have to turn off the always on hibernation or fast boot. Then it will not be so fast. But that will be the only way to boot from grub, and prevent all sorts of issues. –  oldfred

[...] filesystems are left in unsafe states, so any filesystems shared between OSes will almost certainly become damaged when dual-booting like this [fast boot activated] ... Disabling the fast boot options will increase boot times. This is a NECESSARY price of dual-booting with Windows 8. -  Rod Smith

It is not possible to keep fast boot, then the other questions are senseless.